# Read file from csv and remove duplicates rows Java

Tags: java, csv

i have csv file with links and they are separated by commas.
What is the best way to read file and remove dublicates using Java?

```
public class CsvChecker {
public void checkDub()  {
    String csvFile = "D:\\links.csv";

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CsvChecker {
public void checkDub() throws IOException {
    String csvFile = "D:\\links.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String COMA_DELIMITER = ",";
    String NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR = "\n";
    String csv = "D:\\links2.csv";
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(csv);
    HashSet<String> lines = new HashSet<>();



    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (lines.add(line)) {
                fileWriter.append(line);
                fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```